# Finding difference in range of floats in two dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy

I have two dictionaries that I would like to compare and find the different values between the two. Here is an example.

```
dict1={"sex":["Male","Female"],"age":[range(0,100)]}
dict2={"sex":["male","female","Male","Female"],"age":[-10,0.75,2.,2.5,3.5,30.5,0.1167,nan]}
```

I know that I can find the differences between the two by doing this.

```
[In]: set(dict2["sex"])-set(dict1["sex"])
[Out]: {'female','male'}
```

However, when I compare the age, I don't see the expected result. I would like it to return only the negative and nan values.

I tried creating the dictionary this way using numpy but it returns an error saying unhashable type:'numpy.ndarray'

```
dict1={"sex":["Male","Female"],"age":[np.arange(0,100,0.1)]}
dict2={"sex":["male","female","Male","Female"],"age":[-10,0.75,2.,2.5,3.5,30.5,0.1167,nan]}

[In]: set(dict2["age"])-set(dict1["age"])

[Out]: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

My question is, how can I write the range for age in dict1 so that it can represent any positive float from 0 to 100 and only return the negative value and nan from dict 2? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
set(dict2["age"][0])-set(dict1["age"])
```

dict2["age"] is a `list` which consist of one `numpy.ndarray` element

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
dict1={"sex":["Male","Female"],"age":[np.arange(0,100,0.1)]}
```

to

```
dict1={"sex":["Male","Female"],"age":list(np.arange(0,100,0.1))}
#or simply don't put it in list as np.arange itself return an array
dict1={"sex":["Male","Female"],"age":np.arange(0,100,0.1)}
```

Now Output is:

```
>>> set(dict2["age"])-set(dict1["age"])
{0.75, nan, -10, 0.1167}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It really helped. How do I change it so that it will only return -10 and nan? I changed the count by=0.0001 but the script becomes slow.

Comment: can you elaborate what you want